# retrieve user id inside facebook page tab

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to build an app that lets users vote in 4 different categories,
I want to save the User id so that I can make sure someone can only vote once.

I know you can get the user id when a user interacts with the tab, I've read something about `fb_sig_profile_user` but I don't know how to use this.

I've read a little about this on the facebook dev page but it isn't very clear.

If I understand correctly you can get the user id after a user clicks on something and the facebook tab does an ajax call.
Then at that moment you can grab the user id but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

I have many Facebook page tabs that require the Facebook user id to ensure no duplicate entries are made for one user.  What you have to do is step up a Facebook app. Configure it as a Page Tab app and put it on your Facebook page.  Once it is there, then you do a Facebook login popup asking for user permissions.  After that, you can use the SDK to query the current user to get their ID (or you can decode the signed_request form post parameter that facebook posts to your tab app).  You can also do similar things in non-page tab apps wether it is a standalone website or a iFramed canvas app.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but i really dont want people to think that im after some of the private info.
is there no way that i can get the user id without having to aks for extra permission?

Comment: Nope, that's the only way. Plus they're only granting you access to public information anyhow, unless your are asking for more permissions than default.  Also if you cringe that the user might not accept the dialog, then try using the Enhanced Auth dialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will make a POST request to your app with a `signed_request` parameter which, after you decode [as described in the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/), will yield a hash of information such as the **user's country**.

If the user has authorized your app, then that same parameter will contain additional information such as the **user's Facebook id**.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but i really dont want people to think that im after some of the private info.
is there no way that i can get the user id without having to aks for extra permission?

Comment: Everything @DMCS said plus you can still attempt to use other user tracking mechanisms, like http://www.visitorjs.com/ [paid], or roll out your own cookie solution.

Answer (score 0):

//use this to get facebook user id

```
<?php session_start();?>    
    <?php require 'src/facebook.php';
        $app_id = "your_app_id";
        $app_secret = "your_secret_key";
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret

        ));

             $canvas_page = "https://www.facebook.com/page_name/app_appid"; //this is you facebook app url

             $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
                    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

             $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

             list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

             $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

             if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
                    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
             } else {
                    echo $data["user_id"];
                    $_SESSION['fbuser']=$data["user_id"];
             } 
?>
```